# Defer SP.RequestExecutor.executeAsync

Tags: 2013, javascript, sharepoint-addin, apps-development

I'm working on a SharePoint app where I need to run `SP.RequestExecutor.executeAsync()` in order to grab some information from one of the Host Web's lists. Depending on what method is calling the oData call I want to do something different.

Unfortuntely, `executor.executeAsync()` isn't playing as nice as `$.ajax()` does in terms of using `$.when().done()` and executing code *after* an async call is made. Below is some code if you'd like to see:

```
    load = function (){
        $.when(getEntries()).done(function () {
            ViewModels.Calendar.addEventSource(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(eventList));
        });
    }

    getEntries = function () {
        return executor.executeAsync({
            url: appweburl
                + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('" + LIST + "')/items?@target='" + hostweburl
                + "'&$select=Title,OData__x006e_ot5,qnlu,OData__x0066_x20"
                + "&$filter=OData__x0066_x20 eq '" + ViewModels.Person.user.userName() + "' "
                + "and qnlu ge DateTime'" + startDate().toString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "T00:00:00' "
                + "and qnlu le DateTime'" + endDate().toString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "T00:00:00' ",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: onGetEntriesSuccess,
            error: onoDataCallFailure 
        });
    },

    onGetEntriesSuccess = function (data) {
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
        $.each(jsonObject.d.results, function (index, item) {
            eventList.push(new Event(item.qnlu, item.OData__x006e_ot5));
        });
    },

    onoDataCallFailure = function (data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
        alert('Failed to get host site. Error:' + errorMessage);
    };
```

Any ideas/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new .Deferred. Return Deferred.promise from the call. Call Deferred.resolve or Deferred.Reject in the succs and failure handlers.

Answer (score 8):

To add some detail to Scot's answer, you could do something like this:

```
function load () {
    var call = getEntries();
    call.done(function (eventList) {
        ViewModels.Calendar.addEventSource(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(eventList));
    });
}

function getEntries () {
    // create the deferred object
    var def = new $.Deferred();

    executor.executeAsync({
        url: appweburl
            + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('" + LIST + "')/items?@target='" + hostweburl
            + "'&$select=Title,OData__x006e_ot5,qnlu,OData__x0066_x20"
            + "&$filter=OData__x0066_x20 eq '" + ViewModels.Person.user.userName() + "' "
            + "and qnlu ge DateTime'" + startDate().toString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "T00:00:00' "
            + "and qnlu le DateTime'" + endDate().toString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "T00:00:00' ",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: onGetEntriesSuccess,
        error: onoDataCallFailure 
    });

    function onGetEntriesSuccess (data) {
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
        var eventList = [];
        $.each(jsonObject.d.results, function (index, item) {
            eventList.push(new Event(item.qnlu, item.OData__x006e_ot5));
        });

        // resolve the deferred object
        // eventList will be passed as parameter to done
        def.resolve(eventList);
    }

    function onoDataCallFailure (data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
        // reject the deferred object            
        def.reject('Failed to get host site. Error:' + errorMessage);
    }

    // return the promise
    return def.promise();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. I'll keep it around for further reference. In the meantime I was able to work around it and it's been a while since I looked at the code so I think I'll keep it stable for now but again, this will be extremely useful going forward.

Comment: Sorry, I edited again because the suggested edit was wrong. return def.promise(); is the right way to return promises. With the previous edit, what was returned is the original Deferred object, not the promise. It's a slight difference, but it's different (a promise hides the underlying Deferred state, then thus cannot be changed).

Comment: You can use both, but as you say, there was not real wrong in the original post. Let's revert this to it's original state

Comment: I have to make multiple ajax calls, how can I loop them with the SP.RequestExecutor?